# If you haven't seen it, there is a new code of conduct. What do you think?

Tags: discussion

I am 100% in favor of a clear code of conduct for all online communities. I am largely in favor of the updated [Code of Conduct](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/conduct) for Stackexchange. I particular like the fact that it specifically calls out that this applies to mods just like anyone else. I'm also interested in what our community thinks about it in terms of our own specific circumstances, though.

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 7):

I'm totally on board.  There are a lot of things which I have frequently felt a bit frustrated over since you have to go searching all over meta to find a reference when someone starts acting rude.  For instance, this whole question of "you could Google this in 10 seconds..."

I frequently finding myself running to meta, spending several minutes searching for an appropriate community approved reference for pointing out how someone has violated the community accepted code of conduct.  I appreciate how much of this has been clearly iterated in the new code of conduct.  Quick reference, time saved, me happy.  ;)